# ViewModel doesn't display related data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a view model called RegisterViewModel -

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and two models called User and UserDetails

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
}


 public class UserDetails
    {

        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

In my Users controller I have the following for my details method -

```
public ViewResult Details(string id)
        {
            User user = context.Users
                .Include (i => i.UserDetails)
                .Where(i => i.UserName == id)
                .Single();

            user.UserDetails = new UserDetails();

            RegisterViewModel viewModel = new RegisterViewModel{
                UserName = user.UserName,
                FirstName = user.UserDetails.FirstName,
                LastName = user.UserDetails.LastName,
                Salary = user.UserDetails.Salary,
                Email = user.Email,
                Roles = user.Roles
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

And in my details view -

```
@model TRS.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel
<table>
<tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td>@Model.UserName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>@Model.Email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>@Model.FirstName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>@Model.LastName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Roles</td>
    <td>@foreach (Role role in Model.Roles) {
        @role.RoleName<br />
    }</td>
</tr>
```

But I am only getting the date from the User model, nothing for UserDetails. So I can see the username, email and rolles but not the first or Last name.

Can you see where I've gone wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

remove the line

```
user.UserDetails = new UserDetails();
```

doing that, you create a new empty `UserDetails` instance.

And the `user.UserDetails` coming from your context is replaced by that empty instance.

**EDIT**

probably better to avoid NRE

```
user.UserDetails = user.UserDetails ?? new UserDetails();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use user.UserDetails = new UserDetails() it change details from db to new details. You can get your viewmodel in linq request:

```
public ViewResult Details(string id)
    {
        var viewmodel = context.Users
            .Where(i => i.UserName == id)
            .Select(user=>new RegisterViewModel
                {
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    FirstName = user.UserDetails.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.UserDetails.LastName,
                    Salary = user.UserDetails.Salary,
                    Email = user.Email,
                    Roles = user.Roles
                })
            .Single();


        return View(viewModel);
    }
```